# react-native: react-navigation drawer labels

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to have drawer labels/separators in the drawer navigator.

[Somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugU38.jpg)

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. What you are looking at is called `contentComponent`. Basically you will need to inject a `contentComponent` prop into your Drawer navigator.

> **`contentComponent`** Component used to render the content of the drawer, for example, navigation items. Receives the navigation prop for the drawer. [Read more here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer#Example)

```
import DrawerContent from '../app/components/DrawerContent'
const drawerConfiguration = {
    initialRouteName: 'MainStackNavigatior',
    headerMode: 'screen',
    drawerWidth: deviceWidth / 1.38,
    contentComponent: DrawerContent
}
```

Where `contentComponent` is just a `ScrollView` containing a list of customisable items.

```
class DrawerContent extends Component {
  onItemPress(item) {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate(item.key);
  }

  renderDrawerItem(route) {
    const { drawerItems } = this.props;
    if (drawerItems.indexOf(route.key) > -1) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.drawerItem} key={route.key} onPress={() => this.onItemPress(route)}>
          <Text>{route.routeName}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation, isFetching, drawerItemsTitle } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!isFetching && <View style={styles.drawerItemTitle}>
          <Text style={styles.drawerItemTitleText}>{drawerItemsTitle}</Text>
        </View>}
        {!isFetching && <View>
          {navigation.state.routes.map(route => this.renderDrawerItem(route))}
        </View>}
        {isFetching && <View style={styles.spinnerViewBg}>
          <View style={styles.spinner}>
            <ActivityIndicator
              size="small"
              animating
            />
          </View>
        </View>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a good example from Infinite Red. [Tutorial link](https://shift.infinite.red/react-navigation-drawer-tutorial-a802fc3ee6dc)

As for the separators, it is basically a `View` with minimal height and certain width. I believe you can figure it out :) Good luck!